# Augmented Reality (AR) For React Native Project

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, augmented-reality

I've been searching the web for the right cross-platform (IOS & Android) `AR` framework to use with `React Native` but couldn't find any good up-to-date information on this, all I could find is old posts or **backdated** StackOverflow questions which are essentially *worthless* as this is such an evolving technology.

I'm working on a React Native mobile app in which a user should be able to take a picture of any object, and when someone scans that object it should be matched and verified with the previously saved object.

Can anyone share their experience with such projects using React Native or someplace I could find relevant up-to-date information?

Comment: [Viro React](https://github.com/viromedia/viro) Seams to be quite fitting for what you are trying to do, I have not used it personnaly but it seams rather active and up to date.

Comment: @Nicolas It does not sound very popular, do you have an idea on the community?

Comment: From what i could gather from Github, it seams somewhat active, lots of watch and starts is usually a good sign. You could also look for question on stackoveflow containing this tag, to give you an idea of the community.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently according to [this post](https://marmelab.com/blog/2019/04/25/react-native-augmented-reality.html) , https://viromedia.com/viroreact is the kind of tool you are looking for. ***[didn't see the link in the comments, but this was mentioned before my post]***

There's also https://facebook.github.io/react-360/, but last time I checked it was not yet very advanced.

The only experiences I had actually with mobile development of AR was with Unity3D which I don't know if you also considered to use or not, since it can produce mobile apps both for iOS and Android, and has amazing support for VR/AR apps.

Comment: It looks like Viro is now open source https://github.com/viromedia/viro